# If not variable condition is not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to check whether the variable value is false or true, here is my code

```
$print_ready_flag = $_GET['print_ready']; // i'm passing it as either true or false

echo $print_ready_flag ; // I'm getting correct value
```

What i'm trying to do is,

```
if ($print_ready_flag == false) {
     file_name = "albumpdf_" . $Order['products_name'] . "_" . $OrderId . "_" . $OrderPId . ".pdf";
}
```

when doing like above expression is evaluating, But when i tried

> if (!$print_ready_flag) {,
>
> if (!(bool)$print_ready_flag)

. expression is not evaluating. Is there any way to evaluate the expression with out using comparison operator.

Comment: than try `if ($print_ready_flag === false) {` before this, also check `var_dump($print_ready_flag)`

Comment: Yeah i saw this too when i searched in google. is there any other way without using operators?

Comment: i'm passing either true or false for that variable. so isset and empty not working

Comment: yes, in this case `isset()` will always be isset

Comment: dont know y u are u not using operator... solution with ternary: `$status = ($print_ready_flag ? false : true)` just an example

Comment: and u have typo here `file_name`

Comment: I was trying is there any other way to do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127785/discussion-between-devpro-and-anju).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your all conditions are looks fine. you must need to add php `error_reporting() in your code, this will help you to find syntax and warnings.

You have a typo here:

```
// missing $ sign
file_name = "albumpdf_" . $Order['products_name'] . "_" . $OrderId . "_" . $OrderPId . ".pdf";
```

And its better to use `print_ready=0` instead of `print_ready=false` for `$_GET`.
Otherwise, you must need to check with `===` for `value+dataType`

Comment: @Anju: glad to help u

Answer (score 1):

```
$print_ready_flag = $_GET['print_ready']; 

echo $print_ready_flag ; // I'm getting correct value 
$print_ready_flag = filter_var($print_ready_flag, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
if ($print_ready_flag == false) {
  file_name = "albumpdf_" . $Order['products_name'] . "_" . $OrderId . "_" . $OrderPId . ".pdf";
}
```